# Return char* from function on another library

Tags: c++, memory, char

I'm having troubles dealing with pointer when it comes to using another library function

The library has a void function where it modifies a long value by reference successfully, but when trying to modify the value of a char*, the memory allocation from the library gets lost when the function ends, leaving me with unable to read memory.

I don't know what the size of the char* the function will create, so I can't allocate memory before it.

Any help?

EDIT1: posting some code example
EDIT2: posted 2 solutions
Main program:

```
char* resizedPixels = new char[2]; // random number to initialize it
long pixelsSizeRed;

//calling the method from another library
ImageResizer::reziseImg("C:\img.jpg", &resizedPixels, pixelsSizeRef);
// end of main program
```

on the library side, the function is as follows:

```
void resizeImg(char* inputPath, char** resizedPixels, long &pixelsSize){

    pixelsSize=100; //calculated with other methods, hands out the value correctly
    //now that I have the size, allocate memory on the char array I need
    *resizedPixels = new char[pixelsSize];

    //modify inputPath bytes, and passing them to resizedPixels
    char* buffer = "something manipulated";

    for (int i = 0; i < pixelsSize; ++i) {
        (*resizedPixels)[i] = buffer[i];
    }

}
```

Solution 2: using vectors

```
void resizeImg(vector<char>&, long );

int main() {
    vector<char> pixelVec;
    char* resizedPixels;
    long pixelsSizeRef;
    resizeImg(pixelVec, pixelsSizeRef);
    // for loop to pass value
    resizedPixels=new char[pixelsSizeRef];
    for(int i=0; i<pixelsSizeRef; i++){
       resizedPixels[i]=pixelVec.at(i);
    }
    //our char* has the values from library's function

    return 0;
}

void resizeImg(vector<char> &myVec, long pixelSize) {

    // modify your string
    pixelSize=10;
    char foo[pixelSize] = "abcdefghi";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        myVec.push_back(foo[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post at least the method signature you are talking about and probably some code that shows your problem.

Comment: *"but when trying to modify the value of a char\*, the memory allocation from the library gets lost when the function ends, leaving me with unable to read memory"* - How do you know? What tests did you do?

Comment: Debugging with visual studio lets me know that

Comment: In this example code you are passing an uninitialized pointer to a function where you (presumably, based on the comment) try to copy your bytes to, which invokes *undefined behavior* (as your `resizedPixels` pointer is not pointing at valid memory)

Comment: @UnholySheep indeed, that loop to copy bytes is the part of the problem I haven't solved yet. imagine if I initialize the pointer in the main program with a value above what I expect it to be, even that way, the value won't come out of the library

Comment: Either the library is broken or you left out a `&`.

Comment: @molbdnilo even if I pass the pointer by reference, would't it be pointing to memory inside the library? thus, when the function of the library end, would be dead memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the value is lost is because you try to modify a pointer in a function by passing it by value (you pass a `char*`). You need to pass it by pointer (so a `char**`) if you want to modify it within the function and have that modification reflected outside of it.

Think about it the same way you would think about a function which is supposed to modify an `int`. You would need to pass a pointer on the integer (a `int*`) for the modification to be reflected outside the function. Here, you pass your `char*` by value, so that in the function, there is a different object of type `char*` that is constructed, and on which all your manipulation are done. Once you exit the function, that object on which everything has been done is destructed, and you never actually touched the object in the caller block that you wanted to modify in the first place.

I wrote a minimal functioning code of a function that modify a `char*` which you can use as an example if you want to modify accordingly your code (put it in a .cpp file and run it) :

```
#include <iostream>

void resizeImg(char** myarray);

int main() {
    char* resizedPixels;
    resizedPixels = new char[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        resizedPixels[i] = i + 65;
    }
    resizedPixels[4] = '\0';
    std::cout << resizedPixels << std::endl;
    resizeImg(&resizedPixels);
    std::cout << resizedPixels << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void resizeImg(char** myarray) {

    // allocate memory for your string 
    // (you can do that with your pixelSize, 
    // don't forget that the last char is '\0')
    *myarray = new char[10];

    // modify your string
    char foo[10] = "abcdefghi";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        (*myarray)[i] = foo[i];
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
ABCD
abcdefghi
```

Here, the `char*` is passed by pointer, so that the prototype of the function takes a `char**`. And it actually modifies the string from the caller block.

Comment: this answers my question perfectly, even though I found a similar solution working with vectors, once they allocate their own memory. thank you!